# $X\in M_{n,1}(\Bbb Z)$, $f(X)$ is the smallest natural common multiple of its elements, find all $A\in\mathcal M_n(\Bbb Z)$ such that $f(X)=f(AX)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

For a column matrix $X\in\mathcal M_{n,1}(\Bbb Z)$ we define $f(X)$ as the smallest natural common multiple of its elements. Find all matrices $A\in\mathcal M_n(\Bbb Z)$ such that $f(X)=f(AX)$, $\forall X\in\mathcal M_{n,1}(\Bbb Z)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X$ has some coordinate equal to $0$ if and only if $f(X)=0$.

Let $A=[a_{ij}]$. We assume that $\forall X\in\mathcal M_{n,1}(\Bbb Z):f(X)=f(AX)$.

We can use

$f(AX)=0\iff f(X)=0$

to narrow down our search.

$\\$

Suppose you can find $i,j_1,j_2$ such that $j_1\neq j_2$ and $a_{ij_1}\neq 0$ and $a_{ij_2}\neq 0$. In other words, the $i^\text{th}$ row of $A$ has at least two non-zero entries.

Then for that specific $i$, there would exist **non-zero** numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ such that $\sum a_{ij}x_j=0$. I'll let you come up with a construction that proves this.

So, letting $X=[x_j]$, we would have $f(X)\neq0$ but $f(AX)=0$.

This would not be consistent with $\forall X\in\mathcal M_{n,1}(\Bbb Z):f(X)=f(AX)$.

$\\$

Therefore, each row of $A$ has at most one non-zero entry.

On the other hand, if for some $k$ the $k^\text{th}$ row of $A$ were all zero entries,

then even for $f(X)\neq0$ and for that $k$, the $k^\text{th}$ coordinate of $AX$ would be $0$, so that $f(AX)=0$. Again this would not be consistent with $\forall X\in\mathcal M_{n,1}(\Bbb Z):f(X)=f(AX)$.

**It turns out that each row of $A$ has exactly one non-zero entry.**

$\\$

It follows that either each column of $A$ also has exactly one non-zero entry, or else some column of $A$ would be all zero entries. (This is a consequence of the pigeonhole principle.)

Suppose that for some $k$ the $k^\text{th}$ column of $A$ were all zero entries. Then for that $k$, when you look at some specific $X=[x_j]$ where $f(X)\neq0$, the value of $f(AX)$ would not depend on the value of $x_k$. So by increasing $x_k$, you could make $f(X)$ arbitrarily large without changing $f(AX)$ at all. Again this would not be consistent with $\forall X\in\mathcal M_{n,1}(\Bbb Z):f(X)=f(AX)$.

**We deduce that each column of $A$ has exactly one non-zero entry.**

It won't be very difficult to show that these non-zero entries must all be elements of $\{1,-1\}$.

$\\$

On the other hand, every $n$-by-$n$ integer matrix $B$ satisfying the three conditions

- each row has exactly one non-zero entry
- each column has exactly one non-zero entry
- every non-zero entry is an element of $\{1,-1\}$

also satisfies $\forall X\in\mathcal M_{n,1}(\Bbb Z):f(X)=f(BX)$.

What $B$ does, if $B$ satisfies the three conditions, is to permute the entries of $X$, then in some cases multiplying some of the entries by $-1$.

Comment: When you said that "Suppose that for some $k$ the $k^\text{th}$ column of $A$ were all non-zero entries", did you mean that every element in the $k^\text{th}$ column is $0$?

Comment: indeed I did mean that

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n\}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$ and $e=(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$. We first show that $A$ is nonsingular. Suppose $Ax=0$ for some integer vector $x$. For each index $i$, the $i$-th element of $x-x_ie^T$ is zero. Therefore
$$
0=f\left(x-x_ie\right)
=f\left(A(x-x_ie)\right)
=f(A(-x_ie))=f(-x_ie)=|x_i|
$$
for every $i$. Hence $x=0$ and $A$ is nonsingular.

Now let $v=e-e_i$. For any prime number $p$, we have
$$
f\left(pAe_i+Av\right)
=f\left(A(pe_i+v)\right)
=f\left(pe_i+v\right)
=f((1,\ldots,1,p,1,\ldots,1)^T)=p.
$$
Thus $pAe_i+Av$ is a vector with exactly one element equal to $\pm p$ and all other elements equal to $\pm1$. Since $p$ is arbitrarily large, we must have $Ae_i=\pm e_j$ for some $j$. It follows from the non-singularity of $A$ that $A$ is an entrywise signed permutation matrix, i.e., $A=DP$ for some diagonal matrix $D=\operatorname{diag}(\pm1,\ldots,\pm1)$ and permutation matrix $P$. Clearly any $A$ of this form does satisfy the condition that $f(Ax)=f(x)$ for every integer vector $x$. Therefore the solution set is precisely the set of all entrywise signed permutation matrices.